# d3 force graph append an arc into a node

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to append an arc to a node of a graph, if I write like this way, it works:

```
var arc = d3.arc()
            .innerRadius(13)
            .outerRadius(43)
            .startAngle(0)
            .endAngle(2 * Math.PI);

var result = d3.select(".nodes")
    .append("path")
    .attr("d", arc)
    .attr("fill", "lightgrey")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")");
```

the "d.x" and "d.y" is actually the node I clicked.

However, if I just select the node by using the clicked node id:

```
   var result = d3.select("name_"+d.id)
    .append("path")
    .attr("d", arc)
    .attr("fill", "lightgrey")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")");
```

It doesn't work. I can print out the result successfully:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
```

I am just wondering why I can't just select by id? Thanks.

Comment: I am sorry for a typo:var result = d3.select("#name_"+d.id)but notvar result = d3.select("name_"+d.id)

Comment: You can click the 'edit' link to correct typos in your original post.

Answer (score 0):

To select by ID, you can do it in following way :

```
  var output = "name_"+d.id;

  var result = d3.select("[id=" + output + "]")
    .append("path")
    .attr("d", arc)
    .attr("fill", "lightgrey")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")");
```